# Is the objects of tkinter.Tk independent of each other?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, tcl

I write a python script (named script2.py) which includes tkinter. To be convenient, I write a function at the bottom. It looks like:

```
import tkinter
import pygubu

class GuiApp2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.builder=pygubu.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('test.ui')

        self.builder.get_object('Frame_main',master)
        self.list_box_a=self.builder.get_object('Listbox_a')

        self.lba_value_set=tkinter.StringVar()
        self.list_box_a['listvariable']=self.lba_value_set

    def set_value_set(self,the_value_set):
        self.lba_value_set.set(the_value_set)


def run(the_value_set):
    master=tkinter.Tk()
    app=GuiApp1(master)
    app.set_value_set(the_value_set)
    master.mainloop()

def main():
    run(['1','2','3'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then I write another script (named script1.py) which calls the function at the bottom of the script above. It is:

```
import tkinter
import pygubu

import script2

class GuiApp1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.builder=pygubu.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('mainapp.ui')

        self.builder.get_object('Frame_main',master)
        self.button_show=self.builder.get_object('Button_show')

        self.button_show['command']=self.command_for_button_show

    def command_for_button_show(self):
        script2.run(['1','2','3'])


def main():
    master=tkinter.Tk()
    app=GuiApp1(master)
    master.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run script2.py, everything is fine. But when I run script1.py which imports script2.py the Listbox in script2.py is empty.

Of course, these two scripts are not the files I use in my project. The files I really use is too long and difficult to read.

In order to find out the problem, I inserted several `print` functions in my script to show the values of the variable in my scripts. Finally, every print result is fine except the Listbox.

Thus I simplified the real scripts to these scripts which are easy to read.

I guess maybe the `master(tkinter.Tk())` in script1.py affect the `master` in script2.py. Because the logic of GUI Management in tkinter is different from it in dotNet.

Is there anyone who's met a similar problem or have some idea about that?

Comment: Could you provide Screenshots maybe? Not everyone necessarily has `pygubu`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are independent. Each time you create an instance of `Tk`, you create a new instance of an embedded Tcl interpreter. As a consequence, the widgets in one know nothing about the widgets in another.

A well written tkinter program should never create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows you should create instances of `Toplevel`. You also should call `mainloop()` exactly once.

Comment: Yes, but I just want to make the program more reusable that several script use content in script2.py and script1 is just one of them. However as the program developing, there might be more and more script use script2.py. In Addition, in the future, script2.py can be used in other projects.

Comment: @EndlessWay: regardless, you shouldn't be creating more than one instance of `Tk`.